# How to NOT change the path/uri after applying a style?

Tags: 7, media

I'm working on a module. It uses an API to serve images. One of it's features is calling for a custom resolution image by GET request. So for example

myapi.com/img4324342?w=22&h=55.

I'm currently abusing the style function from the Image module.

I call hook_preprocess_image() and if it detects my effect (my custom style that has my custom effect) it has to return a modified path. But the path get's malformed when I apply a style. I just want to have the original URI so I can use the information inside to construct a REST call. How to prevent that the URI changes after style a.k.a. how to return the original URI as Path?

**Background:**

It's a brand portal and I'm an intern making the drupal plugin. The company I work for doesn't want the images to be served from the Drupal hosting, only provided by the API. But they ALSO want that adding a different banner for example to every article is still done the same way you normally do: by adding a image style and adding it as a field to the content type

The $vars variabele from `hook_preprocess_image()` in json looks like this:

```
{
 "path":"?itok=D1zdawxe",
 "alt":null,
 "style_name":"thumbnail",
 "width":null,
 "height":null,
 "title":null,
 "attributes":[],
 "theme_hook_original":"image",
 "theme_hook_suggestions":[]
}
```

after applying any effect.

This means that when I don't apply any effect my Path (my Uri) is `myscheme://img23423423432` and when I do apply ANY effect it get's malformed to random gibberish like `?itok=D1zdawxe`

Comment: What does the path change from and to, and why? Do you mean, for example, that `public://image.jpg` changes to `public://styles/foo/image.jpg`? If so, that's what's supposed to happen. To get around it, simply copy the image file you've just created to the path you want to serve it from. You would have to have the original URI to even _get_ the new style URI, so it's not clear why you're asking how to get that - you already have it, surely? You should post the relevant code to resolve all these ambiguities, your current explanation isn't detailed enough to understand what you're doing

Comment: it changes from `myscheme://image423423` to `?itok=D1zdawxe`

Comment: As a result of....what? Where's the code that makes that happen? What are you doing to invoke the image style creation? I know you're extremely reluctant to share any of your code for some reason, but you're not likely to get any help unless you do. People don't have time to prepare an answer based on guesses, they need real information to go on

Comment: I added it to the question as well, but as result of the application of an effect, doesn't matter which one.

Comment: So there's no custom code involved in this at all? How does the "application of an effect" manifest itself?

Comment: I do have a custom effect, but this behaviour happens with all effects. If I can prevent this behaviour inside my custom effect it would be great.

Comment: One more try and I'm afraid I have to move on to clearer requests: how are you "applying a style"? What physical process does that involve? Given that `hook_preprocess_image()` is a hook that gets invoked by the theme system, what do you mean when you say you "call" it?

Comment: Ah ok: the style get's applied by Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » Article » Manage display and then selecting fFormat settings: Image and Image style = mycustomstyle (although the problem still exists when using another style, because it's an external image)

Comment: Getting a bit closer I think - you should probably be implementing `hook_preprocess_image_style` instead (that comes before `theme_image()` in this case) - see what vars you have available in that hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a kinda nasty solution:

```
hook_preprocess_image_style(&$variables) {
    $variables['uri'] = $variables['path'];
}

hook_preprocess_image(&$vars) {
    if(array_key_exists('uri', $vars)) {
        $vars['path'] = $vars['uri'];
    }

    if(!isset($vars['style_name'])){
        return FALSE;
    }

    $image_styles = image_styles();

    foreach ($image_styles as $image_style_key => $image_style) {
        if ($vars['style_name'] == $image_style_key) {
            foreach ($image_style['effects'] as $effect_key => $effect) {
                if ($effect['name'] == 'myEffect') {
                    $vars['path'] = generateAPIURL($vars['path'], $effect['data']); //get baseURL from path and URL parameters from data
                    break;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```